# Pandas: Exporting multiple DataFrames to multiple xlsx files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx

I have multiple DataFrames (DF), such as

- df1
- df2
- ...
- df24

and I would like to export each DF to a separate xlsx file, such as

- 'output_T1.xlsx' for df1,
- 'output_T2.xlsx' for df2
- ...
- 'output_T24.xlsx' for df24.

Although I know how to do it with to_csv:

```
df[i].to_csv('output_T%s.csv' %(1+i), index = False)
```

I cannot find out how to do it with the df.to_excel. 
Here is my code what I made and I receive a type error.

```
for i in xrange(n):
    writer[i] = pd.ExcelWriter('output_P%s.xlsx')
    dfLP[i].to_excel(writer[i], sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.save()
    %(1+i)
```

TypeError: '_XlsxWriter' object does not support item assignment

Any hint, suggestion would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: It is an ExcelWriter object, according to the description on pandas's website: [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
writer[i] = pd.ExcelWriter('output_P%s.xlsx')
```

You say `writer` is an `ExcelWriter`.  So why do you try to assign to its `[i]`th element?  Try this:

```
for i in xrange(n):
    filename = 'output_P%s.xlsx' % (1+i)
    dfLP[i].to_excel(filename, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```